# How to find/get class object from a class method, static method or instance method

Tags: python, inspect

For example.

```
class Klass:
    def f(sel):
        pass

f = Klass().f()
klass = # i want to get Klass object.
```

I searched a methond in inspect module but I can not find, Actually I find a private function named _findclass but this method does not run correctly in local class for example

```
def test():
   class K:
        def f(self):
            pass
   class_object = _findclass(K().f())
```

Comment: donnt call the method `out = f = Klass().f`

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the output of a function, you can't get any information about it. In your example, `Klass().f()` returns `None`. Once this value is returned, it is indistinguishable from any other `None`. But if you instead do `f = Klass().f`, you can get the instance with `f.__self__`.

For example:

```
class Klass:
    def f(self):
        pass

obj = Klass()
f = obj.f
print(f.__self__ is obj) # prints True
obj.foo = 4
print(f.__self__.foo) # prints 4
```

If you want to get the class, you can use `__class__`:

`print(f.__self__.__class__` is the same thing as `Klass`

If you really need the class from the output, you could try having every method return its class:

```
class Klass:
    def f(self):
        normal_result = "whatever"
        return normal_result, Klass

result, cls = Klass().f()
```

Comment: But I want to find the obj with an inside decorator.